# Rails: trouble sorting array from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, view

So I'm trying to let the user sort an array of recipes from a link in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Score", recipes_sort_path, :order => 'score' %>
```

I send the parameter "score" to my controller method "sort", which looks like this:

```
  def sort
    if (params[:order] == 'score')
      @recipes.sort_by(&:score)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_path }
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
  end
```

It redirects to the following index method:

```
  def index
    # If recipes already present, skip following
    if (!@recipes)
      if (params[:search] || params[:tag])
        @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search], params[:tag])
      else
        @recipes = Recipe.all
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
  end
```

The idea was to be redirected to the index view with the sorted list and just render the view.
I get no errors, but when I click the link, the page reloads but nothing happens.

The Recipe class looks like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :instructions, :name, :slug, :score, :upvotes, :downvotes, :comments, :image

  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comments  
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :to => :user, :prefix => :user, :allow_nil => true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :name, :presence => true

  def score
    score = (self.upvotes - self.downvotes)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a third option (the first 2 is from ckruse's answer).  You can render the index template from the sort action

```
def sort
  if (params[:order] == 'score')
    @recipes.sort_by!(&:score)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
    format.json { render json: @recipe }
  end
end
```

This will use the index template while using @recipes in the sort action.  You also save one request because you're not redirecting.

One more thing I'd like to comment on is the link.  It should be

```
<%= link_to "Score", recipes_sort_path(:order => 'score') %>
```

UPDATE: fetching @recipes.  As much as possible, I want sql to do the sorting so that's what I'm going to do here.

```
def sort
  @recipes = Recipe

  if params[:order] == 'score'
    @recipes = @recipes.order('upvotes - downvotes')
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
    format.json { render json: @recipe }
  end
end
```

Comment: `@recipes` is still blank in your example.

Comment: I thought it was clear to you how to get `@recipes` and sort them by score.  You're just having trouble showing a sorted `@recipes`.  Give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear for the OP. He seems to be new in programming business (sorry :)

Comment: Yeah, at least new in this framework, thx.

I went with your sort method example. It Works, thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `sort_by` is not „destructive,” it returns a new array. You may want to use `sort_by!` or save the return value of `sort_by` into `@recipes`.

Second: you do not render anything in your `sort` action at all. If you posted all code, even `@recipes` is empty. You can do two things:

- Retreive the data in your `sort` method as you did in your `index` method and then call `render :index`
- Sort in your `index` method and do not use a `sort` method at all. You can route multiple URIs to the same action.

Comment: Ok, well I got rid of the sort method, but I'm still doing something wrong. I put the sorting in the index method:
'
    if (params[:order] == 'score')
      @recipes.sort! { |r| r.score }
    end

    # render view
'

Comment: Do you call your action with the right parameters? E.g. `http://localhost:3000/recipes?order=score`?